# the convergence in probability of the stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

In Jacod's *Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes*:page 47,thm 4.31 (iii)

$X$ is a semimartingale , $H_n$ are predictable process converge pointwise to $H$ , and $|H^n|\le K$ , where $K$ is a locally bounded predictable process, then $\forall t:H^n\cdot X_t\to H\cdot X_t$ in probability.

First consider when $X\in\mathcal V$ (cadlag , adapted , $X_0=0$ , finite variation on $[0,t],\forall t$ )

I want to prove the conclusion above by markov inequality:
$$\mathbb P\left(|(H^n-H)\cdot X_t|\ge \varepsilon\right)\le\varepsilon^{-1}\mathbb E\left[|(H^n-H)\cdot X_t|\right]$$

since $H^n-H\to 0 $ pointwise and $|H^n-H|\le 2K$  , so I want to use DCT,but I can't prove that $\mathbb E\left[|K\cdot X_t|\right]<\infty$

$$\mathbb E\left[|K\cdot X_t|\right]\le\mathbb E\left[\int_0^t|K_s|d| X_s|\right]\le C\mathbb E| X_t| $$

I can't get $\mathbb E| X_t|<\infty$ from $X\in\mathcal V$.

Thanks a lot！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, $X \in \mathcal{V}$ does not imply $\mathbb{E}(|X_t|)<\infty$. Just consider the process

$$X_t(\omega) := \begin{cases} 0, & t < 1, \\ \frac{1}{\omega}, & t \geq 1 \end{cases}, \qquad \omega \in \Omega := (0,1).$$

on the measurable space $((0,1),\mathcal{B}((0,1)))$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure. Obviously, $X \in \mathcal{V}$, but $\mathbb{E}(|X_t|)=\infty$ for all $t>1$.

---

This means that your argumentation doesn't work this way; however, we can modify it to make it work. Define a sequence of stopping times by

$$\tau_k := \inf\{t>0; |X_t| > k\}.$$

Then

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(|(H^n-H) \bullet X_t|>\epsilon) &= \mathbb{P}(|(H^n-H) \bullet X_t|>\epsilon, \tau_k> t) + \mathbb{P}(|(H^n-H) \bullet X_t|>\epsilon, \tau_k \leq t) \\ &\leq \mathbb{P}(|(H^n-H) \bullet X_t|>\epsilon, \tau_k > t) + \mathbb{P}(\tau_k \leq t)\\ =: I_1+I_2\end{align*}$$

By Markov's inequality

$$I_1 \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}(1_{\{\tau_k>t\}} |(H^n-H) \bullet X_t|).$$

Proceeding as in your argumentation and using $\mathbb{E}(1_{\{\tau_k>t\}} |X_t|) \leq k$, we get $I_1 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Consequently,

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|(H^n-H) \bullet X_t|>\epsilon)\leq \mathbb{P}(\tau_k \leq t).$$

Letting $k \to \infty$, the claim follows.